Capture entire screen without having to use handles or GetDesktopWindow() User32
I am trying to capture my desktop and all windows on there to a bitmap. So far I have managed to capture individual windows via the name. And I have been able to use the User32 dll to get the desktop handle and capture a lot of open windows like that.
However the app that I am trying to capture does not get captured when using the desktop capture method. I can however get it by using the name to get the handle. That way I am able to capture the window only.
However what I really want is a way to do all of that in one command. Without having to get the window handle manually.
If anybody has a way, I would be very gratefull!
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using Point = System.Drawing.Point;

namespace NullmetingAutomation.ImageRecognitionTooling
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides functions to capture the entire screen, or a particular window, and save it to a file.
    /// </summary>
    public class ScreenCapture(int screenWidth, int screenHeight)
    {
        public int ScreenWidth { get; } = screenWidth;
        public int ScreenHeight { get; } = screenHeight;

        /// <summary>
        /// Captures a window bij the windows name. Adds black to the background where the desktop would be.
        /// </summary>
        public Mat? CaptureWindowByName(string windowName)
        {
            IntPtr targetWindowHandle = User32.FindWindow(null, windowName);

            if (targetWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // Get the window's position and size
                User32.RECT windowRect = new(); ;
                User32.GetWindowRect(targetWindowHandle, ref windowRect);

                int windowWidth = windowRect.Right - windowRect.Left;
                int windowHeight = windowRect.Bottom - windowRect.Top;

                using Bitmap windowBitmap = new Bitmap(windowWidth, windowHeight);
                using Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(windowBitmap);
                IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
                User32.PrintWindow(targetWindowHandle, hdc, 0);
                g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);


                using Bitmap screenBitmap = new(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
                using Graphics gScreen = Graphics.FromImage(screenBitmap);
                gScreen.DrawImage(windowBitmap, new Point(windowRect.Left, windowRect.Top));

                var screenshot = screenBitmap.ToMat();
                Console.WriteLine("Screenshot made successfully!");
                return screenshot;
                    

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Window not found.");
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of the entire desktop
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Mat CaptureScreen(CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation = CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
        {
            //return OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToMat(new Bitmap(CaptureWindow(User32.GetDesktopWindow())));

            using Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
            using var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size, copyPixelOperation);
            return bmp.ToMat();


        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of a specific window
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">The handle to the window. (In windows forms, this is obtained by the Handle property)</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
        {
            // get te hDC of the target window
            IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);
            // get the size
            User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
            User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
            int width = windowRect.Right - windowRect.Left;
            int height = windowRect.Bottom - windowRect.Top;
            // create a device context we can copy to
            IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
            // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
            // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
            IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);
            // select the bitmap object
            IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
            // bitblt over
            GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY);
            // restore selection
            GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
            // clean up
            GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
            User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);
            // get a .NET image object for it
            Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
            // free up the Bitmap object
            GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            return img;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper class containing Gdi32 API functions
        /// </summary>
        private class GDI32
        {

            public const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020; // BitBlt dwRop parameter
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest,
                int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjectSource,
                int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int nWidth,
                int nHeight);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper class containing User32 API functions
        /// </summary>
        private class User32
        {
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct RECT
            {
                public int Left;
                public int Top;
                public int Right;
                public int Bottom;
            }
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, uint nFlags);

        }
    }
}


U can use Screen class and its .Bounds property to get screen rect to use its dimensions in Bitmap.
